# Nagios web interface doesn't accept the credentials

Tags: nagios, nagiosxi

I have a nagios4 instance running in a container and based on "nagios4_inspect" file the credentials are:

```
"NAGIOSADMIN_USER=nagiosadmin",
"NAGIOSADMIN_PASS=nagios",
```

But when I go to the http://localhost/nagios and insert the credentials it doesn't accept it.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It is impossible to help you without additional info...There are many Docker images with Nagios instance....And also, this is not related to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go to below location and reset the password 
sudo htpasswd -c /usr/local/nagios/etc/htpasswd.users nagiosadmin/

Before apply the above command, please verify the file location of htpasswd.